# How to send notification at specific date and time once (firebase cloud messaging)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am a newbie at Firebase cloud functions. I want to make a reminder for only my country. (Turkey)
Timezone UFT+3. The user adds to my real-time database time and date. After that, My cloud function will show him/her a notification that the time has arrived.

First of all here is my real-time database time:

[image]

Also, Here is my cloud function:

```
exports.scheduleremindernotifications = functions.pubsub.schedule("* * * * *").timeZone("Turkey/istanbul").onRun(async (context) => {
  const usersRef = admin.database().ref('users');
  usersRef.once('value', (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
      const userId = childSnapshot.key;
      const consumingRef = admin.database().ref(`users/${userId}/missions`);
      consumingRef.once('value', (snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
          const missions_keys = childSnapshot.key;

          // get it startat value
          const startatref = admin.database().ref(`users/${userId}/missions/${missions_keys}/startat`);

          startatref.once('value', (snapshot) => {
            snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
              const notification_time = childSnapshot.val;

              // time is match it send notification once to that time is came.
              if (notification_time) {
                const payload = {
                  notification: {
                    title: "str",
                    body: "sdadsa"
                  }
                }

                return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("user's token", payload)
                  .then(function(response) {
                  console.log("Notification sent ", response);
                })
                  .catch(function(error) {
                  console.log("Error sending notification: ", error);
                });
              }
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
```

My purpose is:
I created a schedule that works every minute. This function works. Also, I can access startat values. But, I do not know how to send a notification when the time is arrived. Because the function is working every minute. How can I block it? I want to only once send notification. After the sent notification. It would not work.

Comment: I'm not sure what blocking it means for you, but usually I'd remove the node from the database once the `sendToTopic` call has succeeded (so where you now call `console.log("Notification sent ", response);`). Did you try that?

Comment: Blocking means: It works every minute (until forever) so, that means after the once sent notification. It will send again and again. Also, I did not compile it. Because I am afraid of ıt will enter infinity loop.  My app has too many options such as every week, every month, every day. Now, I am only trying to make it once. Lastly, I do not know how to get server time. ( I tried to get to timesnap but I do not get it )

Comment: So as said: how about removing the node from the database once you've sent the notification where you now call `console.log("Notification sent ", response);`? Give it a try and let us know how things go.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud function should be working whenever called from client sides.
It can't be self-triggered.
So cloud function should only contain to send notification with requested information.
It means client sides should call the function at specific times.

If you are developing react based website, you can make a timer module with Javascript and check specific times per minute in order to trigger firebase cloud function.